# Angular: Route from Card to a new View

Tags: html, angular, typescript, bootstrap-4, angular2-routing

I am working on an exercise project in Angular (latest V).

My App instanciates bootstrap cards dynamically from an Order Array and show them on my "Order-Item-Component through my template.

I added Routing so that I can update my OrderId on the Browser-Link after a click. It is working.

What I want is: If a user clicks on one of my cards - a whole new View Opens with my Order-Detail-Component for that specific Id. My cards should be invisible in that view. Subsequently, the user can go back to the cards-view with 'back' Link.

I don't know how to route so that my cards are going to be replaced by the Detail View.

Where do I have to place my 'router-outlet' for the detail-comp? I know, that I cannot place it in the same View as my Order-Component - because there are both visible in this case.

Here is my app.routing.ts: (The first route for orders is working fine)

```
import {RouterModule, Routes} from '@angular/router';
import {OrderComponent} from './order/order.component';
import {ORDER_ROUTES} from './order/order.routes';
import {OrderDetailComponent} from './order/order-detail/order-detail.component';


const APP_ROUTES: Routes = [


  { path: '', redirectTo: '/orders', pathMatch: 'full'},
  { path: 'orders', component: OrderComponent},
  { path: 'orders/:id', component: OrderDetailComponent

];


export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot(APP_ROUTES);
```

Here is my Order.Component.html:

```
<div class="container-fluid"><br>
  <h2 id="heading-order"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart f-left "></i>Open Orders</h2>
  <p id="heading-items"> {{ orders.length }} Items </p>
</div>


<app-order-list></app-order-list>



<app-order-completed></app-order-completed>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is the router link that navigates to the order-details component?

Comment: im sry its edited now with my id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able structure your app this way:

app.component.html:

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

routing module:

```
const APP_ROUTES: Routes = [

  { path: '', redirectTo: '/orders', pathMatch: 'full'},
  { path: 'orders', component: OrderComponent},
  { path: 'order-details/:id' component: OrderDetailsComponent}

];
```

order.component.html:

Provide `[routerLink]="['/order-details', id]` on your card, and pass the parameters to identify cards

Order component can also include `<order-completed>` in the view, if you need the completed orders to behave the same way, have them link to order details in the same way as the other orders.

To navigate back to the list of order, in your `order-details.component.html` provide a router link like `routerLink="/orders"`

Comment: but I have to show the 'Id" on my Link? how can I add that?

Comment: Add it to order-details path

Comment: The link is working know :) thx - but know i dont have the ID? how can i pass that... I wrote that to my card: [routerLink]="['/order-details/:id']"

Comment: Updated the answer, refer for how you'd pass id `[routerLink]="['/order-details', id]`

Answer (score 0):

You would use `<router-outlet>` instead of the custom tags `<app-order-list></app-order-list>, <app-order-completed></app-order-completed>` in your app component.

This way you can create child views:

```
const APP_ROUTES: Routes = [
  { path: '', 
    pathMatch: 'full', 
    component: OrderComponent,
    children: [
     { path: 'order-list', component: OrderListComponent},
     { path: 'orders-completed', component: OrderCompletedComponent},
  ]},
];
```

And this is how the `OrderComponent` would look like:

```
<div class="container-fluid"><br>
  <h2 id="heading-order"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart f-left "></i>Open Orders</h2>
  <p id="heading-items"> {{ orders.length }} Items </p>
</div>


<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Then use `routerLink="/orders-completed"` on a `<button>` or `<a>` tag to navigate